# ORA-38824 During APEX 5.1.3 Installation/Upgrade

Tags: oracle, installation, upgrade, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

**Scenario**

1. Tried to install / upgrade Oracle Apex from 3.2 to 5.1.x with Oracle 12.2.x DB.
2. During 5.1.x upgrade installation ( @apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/ ) installation stopped with **ORA-38824** error.
3. Found Oracle Doc ID 2319659.1 - **ORA-38824 During APEX 5.1.3 Installation/Upgrade (Doc ID 2319659.1)**
4. Applied steps suggested in Option 1, error **ORA-38824** error re-occurred

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't enough detail to go on. You say "STILL NO GOOD", but there is no context as to what was wrong in the first place, so please update your question to phrase it as though we have no prior knowledge as to what your issue is. Second you mention "ORA-38824 During..."; again without resorting to other resources I have no idea what this might be, please include relevant details about issues your are facing in the body of the question to make it as easy as possible for those answering questions.

Answer (score 2):

**What Solved for me?**

**Connect to 12.2.x DB**

```
1. cd apex (of Oracle Apex 5.1.x installation directory ).

2. sqlplus sys as sysdba.

3. Alter session set container = PDB Name. ( if installed on PDB - type also show con_name to verify ).
```

**Install Apex 5.1.x / uninstall it / install it again**

```
4. @apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/ ( please check table space name if not default ) .

5. You should receive an error : ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE Command May not Change the EDITIONABLE Property of an Existing Object".

6. @apxremov.sql - will remove Apex Correctly - this what does the Trick.

7. re-run : @apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/ ( please check table space name if not default ).
```

**IMPORTANT : if you would like to keep your OLD VERSION APEX applications and workspaces while apex website export mechanism does not work ( due to the failed install / upgrade ), you should implement the following** :

**( credits go to : https://avdeo.com/tag/apexexport-class/ )**

```
-- Please note that classes12.jar must be in CLASSPATH as well 

set CLASSPATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%\oui\jlib\classes12.jar;%CLASSPATH%;
set JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin

cd C:\temp\apex_5.1.3\apex\utilities

-- Please see check APEXExport options ( for exporting all aps at once or workspaces ), here is an example :
java oracle/apex/APEXExport -db apex-server.db.example.com:1525:apexdb -user <apex_schema> -password <passwd> -applicationid 101
```